# Problem with parented control bones? affect other values that should not be effected

Tags: rigging, constraints, parent

I have two control bones that control the shape key of each eye respectively. And then I have constrain (child of) these bones to one main bone (in center), so that I don't have to grab each bone to control the blink. now the problem is that, I have parented the main blink control bone to the rest of the rig. Now whenever I move the rest of the rig down the character close it's eyes. I don't know what to do now?

Comment: could you share your file so we could test it?

Comment: I can't share the full file but I will try to share the parts that have problem